# UIPicker label different from output

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker populated with an NSarray.  This sends the `row selected` to a text field. I would like to know how to change the name of the rows in my picker.  Sorry if its not clear im  having difficulty explaining what I mean clearly.

[image]

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    arrStatus = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    //One column
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    //set number of rows
    return arrStatus.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set item per row
    return [arrStatus objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [result selectedRowInComponent:0];
    text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear (your question sentence needs to be edited). You say you can display the countries, but I don't see them in your array. Also, what is "result" in the pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: method?

Comment: The "countries" is a hypothetical app example. `Result` is the picker name. Im trying to explain what I want by using an example. Will edit question

Comment: So, if you select a row in the picker you want (in your example) to display the population instead? Where do have that information stored? How to display that depends on the structure of your array.  The "normal" way would be to have an array of dictionaries where one of the key's value would be the country name and another key's value would be the population.  Do you have a structure like that?

Comment: Yeah thats what im after, I just have an array of countries for the example, I dont know where to store or how to implement the population portion of the code.  I Have never used dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think is close to what you want. If you had 2 arrays, one with the country names, and one with the populations (in the same order), you could use the following code to create an array of dictionaries that would contain both values (you could actually use the 2 arrays directly, but that would require that you keep them in sync if you make any changes. It would be better to do it like below):

```
NSMutableArray *arrStatus = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *nameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Albania",@"Brazil",@"Columbia", nil];
    NSArray *popArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@10.3,@200,@50, nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (int i=0; i<nameArray.count; i++) {
        [dict setValue:[nameArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"countryName"];
        [dict setValue:[popArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"poulation"];
        [arrStatus addObject:[dict copy]];
    }
```

Now, in your picker methods, you could do this:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set item per row
    return [[arrStatus objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"countryNames"];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"population"];
}
```

This would put the population numbers in the text field, and the country names in the picker. Notice that I changed the way I got the value in the didSelectRow method -- no need to define selectedRow, the row argument passed into the method has that value already.

The way I put the population numbers in the popArray will only work in OS X 10.8 I think, I'm not sure whether it works in iOS, or if so, in what version.  You would have to replace @10.3, for example, with [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.3] in earlier versions.

Comment: You are using NSNumber literals--you can also use NSArray literals: `@[ obj0, obj1, .., obj_n ]`

Comment: @nielsbot  Thanks for the heads up -- just downloaded 10.8 today, so I was not aware of that one.

Comment: and NSDictionary literals: `@{ key0 : obj0, key1 : obj1, ..., key_n : obj_n }` ;-)

Comment: Getting blank picker & `hides instance variable` here `[arrStatus addObject:[dict copy]];` `NSMutableArray *arrStatus = [NSMutableArray array];
    countries = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Albania",@"Brazil",@"Columbia", nil];
    populate = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10.3",@"200",@"50", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (int i=0; i<countries.count; i++)
    {
     [dict setValue:[countries objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"countryName"];
        [dict setValue:[populate objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"population"];
        [arrStatus addObject:[dict copy]];
}`

Comment: Had  duplicate of `arrStatus` causing warning.  Ok so now xcode complaining that ` [arrStatus addObject:[dict copy]];` No visible @interface for "NSArray" declares the selector "addObject"`

Comment: You should have arrStatus declared as an ivar as an NSMutableArray. Then where you initialize it, it should be arrStatus = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: Ok Sorted it now thanks to your advice, thanks for taking the time to explain this, I really appreciate it!